# Can no longer inspect objects in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a new `React` project and I've noticed that in `Chrome`, I can no longer place my mouse pointer over an object at a `debugger` point to inspect it. When I now put my mouse pointer over an object, nothing happens.

In the picture below, I placed my mouse pointer over `state` object and nothing happened. Before, when I did that, I could open up the object and see its properties and values assigned to them.

[image]

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: This is a bug which will be fixed in the next version of Chrome. You can use Chrome Canary until then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I've faced that bug in Chrome too, my colleagues also did.

I think it's connected with Chrome update.

Comment: Also, [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to understand what you can do before you have enough reputation to comment.